# How to query multiple php values into a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, while-loop

I am using a php `while` statement to query latitude and longitude coordinates into a javascript variable. As of now it gets queried into separate js variables like

```
  var locations = [
     [ "59.911968", "10.709821" ]
                  ];
  var locations = [
     [ "57.701476", "11.97373" ]
                  ];
```

But Im trying to get it like

```
   var locations = [
     [ "59.911968", "10.709821" ]
     [ "57.701476", "11.97373" ]
                  ];
```

The while statement:

```
<?php
   $args = array('post_type' => 'events');
   $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();  
            $lat  = get_field( "gp_latitude" ); 
            $lon  = get_field( "gp_longitude" ); 
?>
<script>
    var locations = [
     [ <?php echo json_encode($lat) ?>, <?php echo json_encode($lon) ?> ]
    ];
</script>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode` supports complex values, you can do:

```
<?php
   $args = array('post_type' => 'events');
   $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        locations = array();
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            $locations[] = array(
                "lat" => get_field( "gp_latitude" ),
                "lng" => get_field( "gp_longitude" ),
            );
endwhile; ?>
<script>
    var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;
</script>
```

I may have messed up the while-loop syntax. The idea is that you collect all the values in `$locations` and then export it to JavaScript once.

Comment: Thank you @halcyon the syntax was a little off but you definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You want to declare the `var locations = []` out of the loop and after `push` each location to the array like:

```
locations.push([ <?php echo json_encode($lat) ?>, <?php echo json_encode($lon) ?> ]);
```

or even easier create the `locations` as an php array and `json_encode` it!

Comment: i guess this is not what OP needs. Don't you think it will create array with all latitudes and all longitudes?